# Babel-preset-react breaks conditional Array.map with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have [some code](https://github.com/gxa/atlas-heatmap/blob/master/src/load/heatmapAxisCategories.js#L24) with the following structure:

```
someArray.map(
  condition ?
    element => ({
      field: element.someField 
    }) :
    element => ({
      field: element.someOtherField
    })
```

I’m building my code with Webpack 2.3.3 and when I use only `babel-preset-es2015` or `babel-preset-env` everything’s fine, but if I add `react` to my presets I get the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/load/heatmapAxisCategories.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in object destructuring pattern (38:27)

  36 |             isDifferential(experiment) ?
  37 |                 columnHeader => ({
> 38 |                     label: columnHeader.displayName,
     |                            ^
  39 |                     id: columnHeader.id,
  40 |                     info:{
  41 |                         trackId:columnHeader.id,
```

This forces me to have two config blocks for JS and JSX files, one with `env`, and another with `react`, respectively. However the above syntax seems innocuous enough. Do you think it’s a bug or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Seems to be a syntax error here `)} :`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo! The original code doesn’t have it and, as I said, compiles fine with `env` or `es2015`. It breaks when adding `react`.

Comment: Seems like a babel parser issue. Wrapping the last arrow function with () helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead i would change the value in the object on the condition:

```js
someArray.map(element => ({
   field: condition ? element.someField : element.someOtherField
}))
```